# Redireccion a Servicio

Tags: linux, iptables

Tengo un servicio que se ejecuta en el router y acabo de cerrar la conexion externa.

Este router tiene la IP 80.20.x.x y la interna 192.168.13.31, ahora tengo un PC que tiene acceso al router con la IP 192.168.13.50 y la otra IP la de mi VPN que es 172.16.0.2, lo que quiero es que cuando haga la peticion de mi IP de la VPN 172.16.0.2:8080 me permita redireccionar a la IP 192.168.13.31:8080.

Estoy tratando de configurar el comando de IPtables pero no me funciona. Estoy usando:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i tun0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT \
--to-destination 172.16.0.2:8080
```

Saludos

Comment: Aparentemente, la sintaxis de iptables es correcta (al menos a mi no me genera error, en iptables v1.8.3) . No entiendo exactamente lo que pretendes, pero intuyo que debieras usar la cadena POSTROUTING de nat?

Answer (score 0):

si no entiendo mal lo que quieres es redireccionar a la IP 192.168.13.31:8080, entonces la IP que le estas diciendo al DNAT esta mal.

Prueba a modificar el comando y dejarlo asi:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i tun0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to 192.168.13.31:8080
```

Si no es eso lo que quieres intenta explicar con mas detalle.

Gracias.